# Should I use lower light level legendary weapons or higher light level lower tier weapons?

Tags: destiny

Is it better for me to use a legendary weapon with a low light level or a rare or uncommon one with a higher light level, for combat?

I know it decreases my light level, but what if the lower weapon has better stats, such as higher impact?

I know I can use weapons to increase the light level of other weapons. Could I potentially use the lower weapon to increase the light level of the legendary weapon, or should I just break it down for parts?

Comment: changing the reference from "gun" to "weapon". Without spoiling, guns are not the only weapons in Destiny.

Comment: Close Voters, there is nothing opinion based about this question, in context of the actual game. This is a question of "how important is the light level", which has an absolute answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Damage of a gun is based off of its light level first, and its impact second. Rarity has no direct effect on damage but legendarys can have perks that would make it better than a lower rarity gun. Unless you find something that is a massive light increase over what you have already, using a weapon with a little bit lower light level is fine compared to using a higher weapon you aren't comfortable with.

Lower light levels cannot be used to increase higher light level gear, you can only infuse something better into something worse. If you find something that is both lower light level and has perks you wouldn't plan on using, just dismantle it for the parts. This goes for both armor and weapons.

Comment: Thanx..i just got a 113 ledgendary but really like my 156 rare gun..i feel obligated  to use the legendary just

Answer (score 0):

Actually your weapon damage is based on it's impact. The light level modifies it in PvE based on the level of what you are fighting. So for example even though you might have a high impact on your weapon if you have a low light score against a high level enemy then you may not even be able to damage then at all. However, if you have a low impact and a high light score against a low level enemy then you are going to blast it's head clean off in spite of your low impact. It is a fairly clever mechanic because in order for Bungee to remove the level advantage from PvP all they had to do was just make PvP ignore the light scores on everything. As far as I can tell your actual level is only used to determine what gear you can equip.